# Não consigo inserir no MongoDB usando Java

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea

Sou novo no mongo, estou tentando fazer um insert no banco mas ele da problema na hora de inserir

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

    public class InsertDriver {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
            DB dB = (new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)).getDB("realdatabase");
            DBCollection dBCollection = dB.getCollection("Channel");
            BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
            basicDBObject.put("name", "guilherme");
            basicDBObject.put("state", "happy");
            dBCollection.insert(basicDBObject);

        }
    }
```

> Error:(14, 21) java: no suitable method found for insert(com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)
>       method com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(com.mongodb.DBObject...) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be converted to com.mongodb.DBObject[])
>       method com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(java.util.List) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be converted to java.util.List)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instalação para funcionar seria dois `.jar`:

- [mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.0.4/mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar)
- [mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.0.0/mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar)

***Ambiente de desenvolvimento NetBeans***

---

Código funcionou depois da instalação desses dois pacotes:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("realdatabase");        
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("channel");
BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
basicDBObject.put("name", "guilherme");
basicDBObject.put("state", "happy");
collection.insert(basicDBObject);
```

só que o método <strike>**getDB**</strike> está obsoleto, e logo não vai funcionar. Então utilize o método `getDatabase`,`MongoDatabase` e `MongoCollection<Document>` que são os mais atuais.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("realdatabase");                
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("channel");

Document doc = new Document();
doc.put("name", "somalia");
doc.put("state", "casado");

collection.insertOne(doc);
```

---

***Ambiente de desenvolvimento IntelliJ IDEA***

---

São também dois `.jar`

- [mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar)
- [bson-2.13.3.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/2.13.3/bson-2.13.3.jar)

[***Referencia de instalação***](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/installation-guide/)

**Observação:** Por esse motivo existem diferenças entre **Ambientes** de desenvolvimento e os pacotes instalados e suas particularidades.

Comment: mesmo instalando os dois .jar ainda não funcionou

Comment: @GuilhermeLima o código está testado no netbeans, o que poderia ser talvez esteja ai o problema, Você pode editar sua questão e colocar o log de erro ou o que não está funcionando por favor?

Comment: feito, estou usando a intellij IDE

Comment: @GuilhermeLima ele está dizendo tipo misturado, você está enviando um dado simples e ele está pedindo um lista desse dado pelo erro.! O engraçado que ele tem as duas formas

Comment: @GuilhermeLima qual das rotinas você está usando eu passei duas?

Comment: estou usando a primeira opção que usa o getDB, tentei a outra também não funcionou

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45683/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-guilherme-lima). @GuilhermeLima

Comment: @GuilhermeLima a solução está ai para a IDEA remova aqueles `.jar` e adicione esses dois no links referentes da resposta. Agora vai funcionar e me de um feedback! Edite a resposta está no final ...